# Numbers not parsing through select / angular v1

Tags: angularjs, sum, html-select

My "value" fields in my select field, should pull through the price from my object arrays in my controller.  But they don't.... I'm trying to run a function on ng-change, to calculate the drinks value + the extras value...  But this doesn't work.

I get blanks and NaNs. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, or if I'm accessing the price correctly, but the function itself should work..

I have two select fields, which display this data in my controller:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
console.log('myCtrl loaded!');

$scope.drinks = [
{id: '0', type: 'latte', text: 'latte', price: 2.50},
{id: '1', type: 'cappucino', text: 'cappucino', price: 2.50 },
{id: '2', type: 'tea', text: 'tea', price: 3.00 },
{id: '3', type: 'flatwhite', text: 'flat white', price: 2.50 },
{id: '4', type: 'coffee', text: 'coffee', price: 2.00 }
];

$scope.extras = [
{id: '1', type: 'latte && cappucino && flatwhite && coffee', text: 'Extra Shot', price: 1.00 },
{id: '2', type: 'latte && cappucino && flatwhite && coffee', text: 'Chocolate', price: 0.50 },
{id: '3', type: 'latte && cappucino && flatwhite && coffee', text: 'Vanilla', price: 0.50 },
{id: '4', type: 'latte && cappucino && flatwhite && coffee', text: 'Caramel', price: 0.50 },
{id: '5', type: 'latte && cappucino && flatwhite && tea', text: 'Mint', price: 0.50 },
{id: '6', type: 'latte && cappucino && flatwhite && coffee && tea', text: 'Ginger', price: 0.50 },
{id: '7', type: 'latte && cappucino && flatwhite && coffee && tea', text: 'Honey', price: 0.50 }
];
```

Here are the select fields in my index.html:

```
 <div class="column is-half">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <select ng-model="selectedTypeName" ng-options="drink.type as drink.text for drink in drinks" value="drink.price" ng-change="drinkValue(value)">
    </select>

    <select ng-model="selectedName" value="extra.price" ng-options="extra.id as extra.text for extra in extras|filter:{type:selectedTypeName}" ng-change="extraValue(value)">
    </select>

  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the sum function, I'm running in the same controller....

```
  // DRINK VALUE CALCULATE
 $scope.drinkValue = function(value) {
const drinkValue = value;
$scope.order = drinkValue;
console.log('first drop down clicked' + drinkValue);


// EVENT VALUE CALCULATE
$scope.extraValue = function(value) {
  const extraValue = Number(value);
  $scope.extraOrder = extraValue.toFixed(2);
  console.log('extra selected is ' + extraValue);

  // TOTAL CALCULATE
  $scope.total = drinkValue + extraValue;
  console.log('final total is ' + $scope.total);
};
};
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the answer got delete by an admin... not sure why...  any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Here's a solution someone posted, but it removes my filters...  http://plnkr.co/edit/wVb2dpFLhWaNwu4k8KtO?p=preview 

So if you were to search for 'tea' in the first drop down, it should return 'Honey, Mint and Ginger' in the second drop down...

Thanks,
Reena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are still learning and an helpful tip is use console or print the values to see what's causing the issue;

http://plnkr.co/edit/CoOXBnfd21wFentfSdH5?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedDrink"
            ng-options="drink as drink.text for drink in drinks"
            value="drink.price" ng-change="drinkValue(selectedDrink.price)">
    </select>

    <select ng-model="selectedExtra" value="extra.price"
            ng-options="extra as extra.text for extra in extras|filter:{type:selectedDrink.type}"
            ng-change="extraValue(selectedExtra.price)">
    </select>
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you for fixing this. how did you fix the issue?  WHat specifically pulled the price through?

Comment: selectedDrink is an object the fix is **filter:{type:selectedDrink.type}**